# C++ Escape Phrase Substring

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stl, web

I'm trying to parse web data coming from a server, and I'm trying to find a more stl version of what I had.

My old code consisted of a for() loop and checked each character of the string against a set of escape characters and used a stringstream to collect the rest. As I'm sure you can imagine, this sort of loop leads to being a high point of failure when reading web data, as I need strict syntax checking.

I'm trying to instead start using the string::find and string::substr functions, but I'm unsure of the best implementation to do it with.

Basically, I want to read a string of data from a server, different data, separated by a comma. (i.e., first,lastname,email@email.com) and separate it at the commas, but read the data in between.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: You should look into regular expressions -- they will let you define a good set of rules for retrieving specific patterns.

Comment: The Boost library has some pretty nifty things like `boost::split` and `boost::regex` you may find useful. Some compilers support new C++11 `std::regex` etc as well. If you are dealing with XML soap requests and responses perhaps TinyXML or another XML parser may lend a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of data are you parsing, but it's always a good idea to use a multi layer architecture. Each layer should implement an abstract function, and each layer should only do one job (like escaping characters).

The number of layers you use depends on the actual steps needed to decode the stream

for your problem I suggest the following layers:

1st: tokenize by ',' and '\n': convert in to some kind of vector of strings

2nd: resolve escapes: decode escape characers

you should use std::stringstream, and process the characters with a loop. unless your format is REALLY simple (like only a single separator character, without escapes), you can't really use any standard function.

Comment: This is more how I'm doing it now. I'm using strtok_s (the VC++ version) to convert data to a map. I check the number of escape characters hit as a first level syntax check. Then, I pass the parsed data off to a higher level function to interpret and use it.

Answer (score 0):

For the learning experience, this is the code I ended up using to parse data into a map. You can use the web_parse_resurn.err to see if an error was hit, or use it for specific error codes.

```
struct web_parse_return {
map<int,string> parsedata;
int err;
};

web_parse_return* parsewebstring(char* escapechar, char* input, int tokenminimum) {                 
int err = 0;
map<int,string> datamap;
if(input == "MISSING_INFO") { //a server-side string for data left out in the call
    err++;
}
else {
    char* nTOKEN;   
    char* TOKEN = strtok_s(input, escapechar,&nTOKEN);
    if(TOKEN != 0) { //if the escape character is found
        int tokencount = 0; 
        while(TOKEN != 0) {//since it finds the next occurrence, keep going
            datamap.insert(pair<int,string>(tokencount,TOKEN));
            TOKEN = strtok_s(NULL, escapechar,&nTOKEN);
            tokencount++;
        }
        if(tokencount < tokenminimum) //check that the right number was hit
            err++; //other wise, up the error count
    }
    else {
        err++;  
    }   
}

web_parse_return* p = new web_parse_return; //initializing a new struct
p->err = err;
p->parsedata = datamap;
return p;
}
```